# Como repetir o valor de um campo em outro campo no select SQL Server

Tags: sql, select, dados-hierárquicos

Tenho uma tabela onde existem os campos: PessoaId, Nome e PessoaPaiId (Que indica que ela é filha de outra pessoa da tabela. e caso ela seja o pai, esse campo fica null).

Preciso extrair um resultado que traga:
Nome Da Pessoa

Comment: Sua pergunta não faz muito sentido. Pelo que você escreveu basta um SELECT Nome FROM sua_tabela; e não tem nada a ver com o título.

Comment: Sua pergunta está incompreensível. Você quer trazer o nome do pai junto com o nome da pessoa?

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi sua pergunta, você quer trazer o nome do pai, juntamente com o nome da pessoa.

Para isso, você pode utilizar um `LEFT JOIN` da tabela Pessoa com ela mesma, relacionando os registros onde o código do Pai é igual ao código do registro.

```
SELECT P.Nome AS NomePessoa,
       Pai.Nome AS NomePai
FROM Pessoa AS P
   LEFT JOIN Pessoa AS Pai
       ON Pai.PessoaId = P.PessoaPaiId
```

O `LEFT JOIN` permite que você traga os registros que não possuem Pai, ou seja, que não possuem relacionamento.